# Ignited datatables, how to use callback function?

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I am using Ignited datatables (for codeigniter) and I'm using the server side.
I would like to show some values in RED or GREEN depending on their values.

This is how I call the function inside the edit_column:

```
->edit_column('releve_statut', '$1', $this->label_this('releve_statut'))
```

And this is the function I'm calling:

```
public function label_this($str) {

    if($str == "Réalisé"){
        $r =  label_badge('success', 'Réalisé'); 
    } else if ($str == "En cours"){
       $r = label_badge('warning', 'En cours'); 
    }

    return $r;

}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks :)

Comment: Could I ask what does the label_badge function does, I'm tempted to put in a CSS solution but I don't really understand what markup that label_badge function creates, and where is it used

Comment: It's for formating the text. It creates a colored badge.
function label_badge($type, $text){
         return '<span class="badge bg-'.$type.'">'.$text.'</span>';
     }
The problem is that the comparison inside my function label_this doesn't work :/

Comment: When I add a third else, it shows the value inside it:
 else {
            $r = 'Error';
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function on the server side didn't work for me :/

The solution that I did is to add **fnDrawCallback** to the datatables initialisation (client side) which is is called on every 'draw' event.

```
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                        var $green = $('.statut-style').filter(function() {
                                    return  ($(this).text() == 'Réalisé');
                                });
                        // Set the green elements to color green
                        $green.addClass("badge bg-success");
      },
```

If anyone know how to do it on the server side, I'll be glad if you share it ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a callback on server side, an easy and painless solution is creating a Codeigniter Helper class.

So, in your code, change the third parameter of `edit_column`:

```
->edit_column('releve_statut', '$1', 'label_this(releve_statut)')
```

Finally, define the function `label_this($str)` in a helper class. Don't forget to load it before calling `$this->datatables->generate()`.

Answer (score 0):

```php
->edit_column('releve_statut', '$1', 'callback_label_this(releve_statut)');
```

[Source](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5133/ignited-datatables-php-library/p1#Comment_22623)

Not an expert on this but I know this is how its done elsewhere in codeigniter so although I can't test, makes sense that this should work

Original (still sort of relevant)
What you need to do here is have a CSS style sheet as so

```
.bg-success{
    color: green;
}
.bg-warning{
    color: red;
}
```

this will style the text as coloured
If you want a coloured background then replace color with background color.

Comment: The problem is that the comparison doesn't work. When I do this:
if($str == "Réalisé"){
            $r =  'AAA'; 
        } else if ($str == "En cours"){
            $r = 'BBB'; 
        } else {
            $r = 'Error';
        }
The result is: 'Errror'!
PS: The values in the database are: enum('','En cours','Réalisé').

Comment: I have edited it now so I think this is what it should be like

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's still not working :/  when i put your code it shows this value inside my table: callback_label_this(releve_statut)